# Disable rubocop for folder, but re-enable for specific files in folder

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I'm trying to disable a cop for an entire folder, but then re-enable the cop for specific files inside the folder.   I've tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```
Lint/AmbiguousBlockAssociation:
  Exclude:
    - 'spec/**/*'
  Include:
    - 'spec/support/**/*'
    - 'spec/factories/**/*'
    - 'spec/rails_helper.rb'
    - 'spec/spec_helper.rb'
```

Is this possible with rubocop?

Comment: I just tried this, and it works fine for me. Can you give a verifiable example to reproduce the issue - i.e. a minimal `.rubocop.yaml` and folder structure?

Comment: BTW although I don't think this is necessary here, one possibility is to define Include/Exclude patterns using a regular expression: `!ruby/regexp <pattern>`

Comment: @TomLord is correct: what you wrote will absolutely work. If it is not working for you, then you have some other issue besides the config file contents.